# Hibernate call restful service on start

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I have a restful service that is successfully mapped to /service but I am trying to execute the service without having to load the /service page in my browser. This is probably a poor question but if someone can send me in the right direction I am trying to understand my problem.

**Question:**
How do I execute a restful service without using my browser to open the `@RequestMapping` page. I would like to do this programmatically and I have been looking through annotations to see if one loads the service.

**Code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/service")
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public String getstuff()
        throws JsonMappingException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    try{

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the annotiation `@Postconstruct` was what I was looking for. Read about it [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I re-read the question and I think I misunderstood. 
I think that what you want is to use a tool that calls the service, other than a browser.
Among the simpler solutions you have:

1. Calling the service programatically. You can use [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html) which is a simple java client for calling such services like the one you have
2. Use **[curl](http://www.yilmazhuseyin.com/blog/dev/curl-tutorial-examples-usage/)** from unix

Comment: Included an edit. I do want to do this programatically, and more specifically using an annotation if such annotation exists.

Comment: I do not know of any method of using annotations for service calls, at least not in the way I think you are describing.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, the client that would call your service must be a separate program. SO you would deploy your service, and then run a second program that is the service client, which would call your service programatically.